# Errors while logging into routers via telnet

Tags: perl, telnet, cisco

I'm new to Perl and i need to write a code to log into a list of routers via Telnet, execute a series of commands, and save the output to a text file. 
All works well, except for when a router fails to log in. I want to be able to check for a successful login, and if unsuccessful, output an error message to the text file and move on to the next router.
Here is the part of the code that reads IP addresses, executes the commands, and saves the output to a text file:

```
    # foreach loop to continue reading lines from the IP address file until EOF
    foreach $ip (<INPUTIP>)
    {
        # output the IP address read from the file
        chomp $ip;

        # open the file to read commands from
        open INPUTCMD, $readCmdsFrom;   

        # open the file to write output to and write IP to it
        open OUTPUT, ">>$writeOutputTo";
        print OUTPUT "For the router with IP address $ip: \n";

        # telnet to router
        $session = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(Host => "$ip");
        $session->login("$username", "$password");

        # foreach loop to continue reading and executing lines from the commands file until EOF
        foreach $command (<INPUTCMD>)
        {
            # output the command read from the file
            chomp $command;

            # execute the line and save output to array
            @output = $session->cmd("$command");

            # write the output of the command to the output file
            print OUTPUT "@output\n";
        }

        # close the router's session
        $session->close;

        # close files
        close OUTPUT;
        close INPUTIP;
        close INPUTCMD;
    }

    # output success message
    print "Commands successfully executed!";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and perl.  Please include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script.  They will make you a better programmer and save you an incalculable amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login failures by default will cause the script to `die`. You can handle this using, for example, `eval`:

```
eval {
    my $session = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(Host => $ip);
    $session->login($username, $password);

    # Other code using $session
    1;
} or do {
    print "ERROR: $!";
    next;
};
```

Alternatively, using `Errmode` you can change the behaviour to instead return `undef` on failure:

> When mode is "return" then the method generating the error places an error message in the object and returns an undefined value in a scalar context and an empty list in list context. The error message may be obtained using errmsg().

e.g.

```
my $session = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(Host => $ip, Errmode => "return");
if (!$session || !$session->login($username, $password)) {
   print "Login Error: $!";
   next;
}
# Continue using $session
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply- I put that in but its now giving me an error message on every router even though the code runs fine without this extra section.

Comment: The error I am getting is Login error Net::Telnet::Cisco=GLOB(0x31cb78)->errmsg which does not make much sense to me. It seems to be executing the if statement whether the login was successful or not.

Comment: I also just tried it using eval and this way it will telnet to the router, do the commands, but then it also prints the login error.

Comment: RobEarl- Looks like I got it working using the second suggestion you gave me. Thanks for your help! :)